# 3-way merge not working on beyond compare 4 with git

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, beyondcompare4

I am unable to do a 3-way merge with beyond compare 4 to resolve any git conflicts. When there are conflicts I type

```
git mergetool
```

it opens a beyond compare tab but instead of a 3-way merge its a normal diff view.

The version of Beyond Compare is Version 4.1.3 (64-bit). The version of git is git version 2.7.1.windows.1 and I am on Windows 7. The relevant section of the .gitconfig is

```
[diff]
    tool = bc3
[difftool "bc3"]
    path = 'c:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe'
[merge]
    tool = bc3
[mergetool "bc3"]
    path = 'c:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe'
    cmd = 'c:/Program files/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe' "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$BASE" "$MERGED"
```

I had tried to follow the instructions given at http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#gitwindows but it did not solve the issue. Can you guys please help me with this? 
Thanks

Comment: Did you use bc instead of bc3?

Comment: @VonC I had tried that but did not work

Answer (score 8):

Are you licensed for Beyond Compare 4 Pro or Beyond Compare 4 Standard? Three-way merge is a pro only feature, if you have a standard license, it only supports 2-way compare.

Open **Help > About Beyond Compare** to display your license type.

If you have a standard license, you can upgrade by paying the difference in license price. Fill out the [upgrade form](http://www.scootersoftware.com/shop.php?zz=shop_upgrade_cart) on Scooter Software's website to upgrade a license.

If you are licensed for Beyond Compare Standard Edition but you want to evaluate Pro Edition features, you can place BC back into trial mode.

To restore trial mode, rename the file where your license key is saved.  If you registered for the current user, it would be saved as something like C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Scooter Software\Beyond Compare 4\BC4Key.txt.  If you registered for all users, it would be in C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\BC4Key.txt.

Close Beyond Compare, then rename the file to something like "BC4Key.back".  Run Beyond Compare, then select About from the Help menu.  Check Evaluate Pro Edition features.  Restart Beyond Compare.  When you are finished evaluating the Pro Edition, rename BC4Key.back to BC4Key.txt to restore your license.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. I missed that completely. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Reinserting registration code worked for me:
[Help -> Enter Key...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iktbq.png)
Then restart beyond compare, *git mergetool* opened in 3-way view (unlike before)